# Ring of integers of cubic number fields

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

I am trying to give an explicit expression of some ideal class groups of cubic number fields. I taking as a reference for the examples *Number Fields* by Daniel A. Marcus, in particular the cubic field on exercise 26, section 5, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{19})$. In this exercise, the author claims that

$R = \mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{19}) = \{\frac{a + b\alpha + c\alpha^{2}}{3} : a \equiv b \equiv c$ (mod 3)$\}$, with $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{19}$,

but I don't understand what leads him to this statement. I know that a basis of $R$ is $\{$ 1, $\alpha$, $\frac{\alpha^{2} \pm \alpha + 1}{3} \}$, but I don't know how to reach the result in question.

Also, in the previous exercise, ex.: 25, section 5, it says that for the cubic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{17})$,

$R = \mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{17}) = \{\frac{a + b\alpha + c\alpha^{2}}{3} : a \equiv c \equiv -b$ (mod 3)$\}$, with $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{17}$,

and also I can't figure out why.

Comment: Alaca and Williams have dealt with cubic number fields and their integral bases in chapter 7 of *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory*. They have given a lot solved examples and also a general theorem by Dedekind for pure cubic fields.

Comment: You already know what the basis is, so you can start with an arbitrary element in $R$, and try to show that by proper choices of coefficients, the two sets are actually the same.